# WinForm: Maximizar y restaurar ventana

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, visual-studio-2019

Un saludo para cada persona que vea esta pregunta.

Tengo un proyecto WinForm, en Visual Studio 2019 Community. El asunto es que quiero cambiar la propiedad `FormBorderStyle` de un formulario para establecerlo en None, y crear una barra de título y botones personalizada.

Normalmente uso este código para maximizar y restaurar ventana:

```
Sub MaxRestForm()
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Else
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    End If
End Sub
```

Ocasionalmente lo modifico así:

```
Sub MaxRestForm()
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal Then
        Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    Else
        If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized Then
            Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Pero mi problema con lo anterior es que cuando tengo la propiedad **FormBorderStyle = None**, el formulario ocupa toda la pantalla al maximizar la ventana.

Buscando por allí me encontré con esta opción para lo anterior:

```
Private Sub MaxRestForm()
    Me.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location
    Me.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size
End Sub
```

Mi problema aquí es que no encuentro respuesta sobre como restaurar la ventana después de usar el código anterior para maximizar la pantalla sin cubrir toda la pantalla, y me gustaría que me ayudaran a resolver este dilema.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso yo uso este código, pero lo tengo en C#, ya tu lo cambias a visual basic.

```
int LY, LX, SW, SH;

    public void Restaurar(Form frm)
    {
        frm.Size = new Size(SW, SH);
        frm.Location = new Point(LX, LY);
    }

    public void Maximizar(Form frm)
    {
        LX = frm.Location.X;
        LY = frm.Location.Y;
        SW = frm.Size.Width;
        SH = frm.Size.Height;
        frm.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
        frm.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
    }
```

Con este código te va a dejar visible la barra de tareas.

Comment: Gracias por leer y responder a mi pregunta, tu respuesta me ha ayudado un poco, pero sigo sin lograr que centre en pantalla tal y como cuando inicia el formulario por primera vez
Actualmente estoy implementando este código: https://github.com/AlexPJ1996/CodigosGuia/blob/main/VB.NET/Test

Comment: Si entiendo bien, quieres que al momento de restaurar la ventana quieres que se centre en la pantalla, el código que te pase, te pone la ventana en el lugar donde estaba antes de maximizarce, si quieres que la ventana se centre en la pantalla usa la propiedad "StartPosition" en la parte donde restauras la ventana

Comment: Ya la probé, y no surte efecto. Utilizé: Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent y Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen, y ninguna de las dos arroja ese resultado

Comment: Si todavía estas buscando, tal vez esto te sirva: 
frmC.Location = new System.Drawing.Point((p_Container.Width - frmC.Width) / 2, (p_Container.Height - frmC.Height) / 2);